# Synonyms for One-to-One Matching Mechanisms

Tags: mechanism-design, definition

I am trying to find a more elegant usage of wording for one-to-one matching and I am need of some thoughts from others. Bilateral matching? Any help would be respected.

Comment: Have you considered "bijection/bijective"?

Comment: No, I did not, but that does remind me of the term way back when I took Linear Algerbra. Sounds fitting! Thank you!